# Laravel Policies - Before / After Update?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I'm a bit confused with what is the best way to use the Policy classes in Laravel.

Lets say I have a `User` and a `Post`, I have a policy method when updating a post that checks that a `User` owns the post.

Should I pass the `Post` object into the `authorize` method immediately after loading it from the database? Or once I have updated the fillable values?

My issue is that if the `user_id` changes on the `Post`, either the authorize method will allow the user to change the post even if they do not own it, or it will allow them to change the user to someone else, meaning they lose access to it.

Does this mean I need to call `$this->authorize('update', $post)` both before and after I update its values?

```
$post = Post::findOrFail($id); 

$this->authorize('update', $post); // Should I call it here

$post->fill($request->input());

$this->authorize('update', $post); // Or here? Or, both places?
```

Alternatively, should I be using Request Validation to ensure that the user cannot enter IDs of entities they cannot access?

Comment: Would you explain how the `user_id` can be changed in your design? I mean Can it be changed through the form submittion??

Comment: I'm just using `User` and `Post` as examples, but yes, imagine there would be a `<select />` box to change the association of who it belongs to, with the new ID being submitted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call $this->authorize('update', $post) before update values

```
$post = Post::findOrFail($id); 

$this->authorize('update', $post); // throw a HttpException if the action is not authorized

$post->fill($request->input());
```

source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization#controller-authorization